# Dynamic queryParams in Ember... is it possible?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I'm using Ember 2.4.1, and i'm currently having trouble trying to run queryParams with dynamic values.

Long story short, the application needs to filter a table by it's columns, but the columns are user generated through the application... So, i need first to get the column results to build a queryParams array.

Problem is that queryParams is executed before the model (i guess), and trying to update it in the afterModel hook, or with an Ember.computed results in a non-functional queryParams. =/

I thought about something with initializer... but the columns generated is based on the selected product... so i don't know if it will be effective.

Does some one here have ever faced some issue like this? Is there a good way to deal with this problem?

Comment: May be you need use actions instead queryParams? It'is not good to change queryParams ... Probabley I bad understood yours question Could you show a code with comments?

Comment: Unfortunately i'm not allowed to post any code due to the company's contract... I know that there is a didQueryParamsUpdated hook, but it will not help me in this... thing is that the queryParams property doesn't accept dynamic data... it needs to be set in the controller as a static array... The main problem is that... how to generate the queryParams property with dynamic results... will update the post with an example.